# How to redirect site member after login

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

One of the problems I encountered in my project was how to redirect a user to your specific site after you login to Alfresco. The solution I found searching in the Alfresco forum can see below.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to modify the site-index.jsp file located in "\Alfrescoe\tomcat\webapps\share", here's the code solution I found in the Alfresco forum:

```
<%@ page import="org.alfresco.web.site.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.extensions.surf.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.extensions.surf.site.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%
   // retrieve user name from the session
   String userid = (String)session.getAttribute(SlingshotUserFactory.SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_KEY_USER_ID);

   // test user dashboard page exists?
   RequestContext context = (RequestContext)request.getAttribute(RequestContext.ATTR_REQUEST_CONTEXT);
   if (context.getObjectService().getPage("user/" + userid + "/dashboard") == null)
   {
      // no user dashboard page found! create initial dashboard for this user...
      Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<String, String>();
      tokens.put("userid", userid);
      FrameworkUtil.getServiceRegistry().getPresetsManager().constructPreset("user-dashboard", tokens);
   }

   // redirect to site or user dashboard as appropriate
   String siteName = request.getParameter("site");
   if (siteName == null || siteName.length() == 0)
   {
      // forward to user specific dashboard page
      response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/page/site/TestSiteExample1/documentlibrary");
   }
   else
   {
      // forward to site specific dashboard page
      response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/page/site/" + URLEncoder.encode(siteName) + "/dashboard"); 
   }
%>
```